# How to filter between a dates from string and datetimepicker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker, date-parsing

I am trying to filter through things by date. I have 2 DateTimePicker called FromDate and ToDate. I have an array and within one of the array (str[10]) is a date, I tried converting the string into a datetime format but I still get the error:

```
System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'
```

The string within str[10]:

```
str[10] = "9/22/2017 18:24";
```

My current code:

```
string[] date = str[10].Split(' ');                            
DateTime dateSpec = DateTime.ParseExact(date[0], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
if (dateSpec >= FromDate.Value && dateSpec <= ToDate.Value) 
{ 
   //Do Something
}
```

I am not so sure what to do as most forums suggest more or less the same thing. I'm not sure where the error is. I checked the array and the string does not have any spaces as well, thinking that it may have been the reason as to why there was an error

Comment: you miss the time part in `"MM/dd/yyyy"`?

Comment: but the thing is, I just wanted to filter it by date unless it is a must with the time as well? bc the array date[0] is just the date "9/22/2017"

Comment: Why are you using strings instead of DateTime object in the first place? If you *absolutely* have to use strings, use they ISO8601 format, YYYY-MM-DD. It's the only unambiguous format and is recognized by `DateTime.Parse`

Comment: Using string instead bc the data of the dates are in an excel file that I had imported into a listbox filtered with only the things i need to see (other data eg: name, etc..), so I wanted to filter it further

Answer (score 2):

The [`MM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#MM_Specifier) in `"MM/dd/yyyy"` means the month component will be padded with a `0`, if necessary, to make it two digits long.  Your input, `"9/22/2017"`, uses only a [single-digit month](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#M_Specifier) and so doesn't match that format.  If you change the format to `"M/dd/yyyy"` it parses successfully.

Also, you don't need to truncate the time portion yourself; if the time format is consistent ([`HH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#HH_Specifier) [`:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#timeSeparator) [`mm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#mmSpecifier)) then just parse it and use the [`Date` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date) to get a `DateTime` for midnight of the same day...

```csharp
DateTime dateSpec = DateTime.ParseExact(str[10], "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
if (dateSpec.Date >= FromDate.Value && dateSpec.Date <= ToDate.Value) 
{ 
    //Do Something
}
```

Depending on how `str` is populated (e.g. user input) also consider using [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact), which returns `false` upon failure rather than throwing a `FormatException`...

```csharp
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str[10], "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dateSpec))
{
    // Handle parsing success

    if (dateSpec.Date >= FromDate.Value && dateSpec.Date <= ToDate.Value) 
    { 
        //Do Something
    }
}
else
{
    // Handle parsing failure
}
```

`dateSpec` is declared at the point it is passed as an `out` parameter, which is [possible since C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier#calling-a-method-with-an-out-argument).

Comment: I am not sure as to why it still isn't working. I tried changing the format to M/d/yyyy H:mm because I looked back onto the list of dates that I have but it still has the same error as an invalid format

Comment: What input string(s) is it failing on?  `"9/22/2017 18:24"` parses for me with `"M/d/yyyy H:mm"`.  Did you change the first argument passed to `ParseExact()` from `date[0]` to `str[10]`?  What is the value of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName`?

Answer (score -2):

I managed to get it working by adding this block of code from another coder's suggestion on another platform

```
string[] formats = { "M/d/yyyy HH:mm", "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm", "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" };
DateTime dateSpec = DateTime.Now;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str[10].ToString(), formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dateSpec))
{
    if (dateSpec.Date >= FromDate.Value.Date && dateSpec.Date <= ToDate.Value.Date)
        {
            //Do Something
        }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

Comment: This is effectively the same as the second code snippet in my answer except you're passing (guessing at?) four formats instead of one.  I have confirmed that, in the invariant and `en-US` cultures, `M/d/yyyy HH:mm` successfully parses all four combinations of one- and two-digit months and days; `MM` fails to parse a single-digit month (`9`) so your last 2, if not 3, formats here seem unnecessary.  It's hard to see how this answer will be useful to anyone but yourself when you provided only one sample input and didn't respond to my clarifying questions in response to your comment on my answer.